# Increased duties during last 2 weeks

Tags: ethics

I have given my 2 weeks notice to my employer.  From what I understand your last 2 weeks is a time to finish up projects and assist in the training and transfer of job duties.  Since I have notice, my employer keeps adding more jobs assignments - things I have never done before and have never been trained on.

Can they do this?

How is this ethical?

I feel I am being set up to refuse so they can weasel out of paying me the accrued vacation time according to their policy of leaving in good standing.

Comment: Depending on locale they may not have a choice about paying you for accrued vacation.

Answer (score 7):

> I have given my 2 weeks notice to my employer. From what i understand
>   your last 2 weeks is a time to finish up projects and assist in the
>   training and transfer of job duites.

Not necessarily.

Some employers concentrate on handing off the duties. Others treat the last 2 weeks as just another 2 weeks of work.

> SInce I have notice, my employer keeps adding more jobs assignments -
>   things I have never done before and have never been trained on. Can
>   they do this? How is this ethical?

Yes they can do this. Yes it is ethical.
You are still an employee. You are being paid to do the work assigned.

> I feel I am being set up to refuse so they can weasel out of paying me
>   the accreud vacation time according to thier policy of leaving in good
>   standing.

You aren't being "set up". Just do the work as assigned and don't refuse.
They aren't going to weasel out of accrued vacation time. In most locales that would be strictly illegal.

It's only 2 weeks. Just do the work and put this job behind you.

Comment: _You aren't being "set up"_ - hear, hear, we have a mind-reader here - how can you know that - have you talked to them? ;-|

Comment: @JoeStrazzere You don't find it odd that suddenly the OP is getting assignments on things that require training?  Things that will need to be handed off along with everything else he's doing because it won't get completed?  I've never seen anything like that.  If I were him I'd certainly document via email and raise as many red flags as is possible.

Answer (score 1):

They are totally allowed to assign you as much work as they like.  There are norms about this, but no rules.  On the flip side, assigning you to work with things you've never touched before is really inefficient, and if they're piling stuff on in your last two weeks, there's a good chance that a lot of it won't get done.  What they *don't* get to do is use the work they've piled onto you as an excuse for why you should stay.

So... if you can handle it in the time allotted, do so.  If you can't, do what any good employee should do in that sort of a situation.  Be upfront and clear about the fact that you won't be able to handle it all, and ask them to prioritize.  Mention the value of being able to hand stuff off, and include any hand-off tasks you might have in that list.  Then work the same hours you would work if you were not leaving in two weeks, do what work you are able, and debrief them before you go.

Answer (score 0):

> Since I have notice, my employer keeps adding more jobs assignments -
>   things I have never done before and have never been trained on.

I have worked at a place that did exactly this.

The manager did this whenever contractor was leaving. They would pile on tasks that were impossible, then on the last day reject all submitted code. The day after the employee left, they would then tell the contracting company that becasue the work was substandard, and they didn't get to the important tasks such as handover, they would not pay the contracting company for those last few weeks of work. The employee still got paid, but the contacting company had to take it out of their profits.

Why did the manager do this? who knows.

I have seen departing employees avoided by management. I have seen management beg them to stay. I have seen them try to guilt them into staying. I have also seen them treat departing properly.

> I feel I am being set up to refuse so they can weasel out of paying me
>   the accrued vacation time according to their policy of leaving in good
>   standing.

It is possible that HR will make getting your benefits difficult. In a small company the way that management treats you may be an indicator of how the benefits will be handled. But in a larger company the manager may be doing this without anybody knowing.

Yes, your manager can add tasks to your assignments to make the best use of your time. As long as the task isn't unsafe or violate some other agreement it is likely to fall under "and other duties as assigned".

My advice is do the best you can. Document your activities in a place that you can get to after your last day just in case they try and say that you left on bad terms.

Comment: This, but also make sure you've flagged the fact that you are likely being given too many tasks, or tasks that you are unfamiliar with, with your manager by email. Highlight that you have concerns a) about your ability to complete this work by your end date and b) about the lack of sufficient time for a hand-over. If they choose to ignore your advice that's on them, but at least there will be a paper trail that you did your best to warn them.